# How to export a documentation from SSAS

Tags: ssas, documentation, cube, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular model built in Analysis Services and I would like to know if it is possible to export documentation with my data sources, tables, roles, relationships and measures?

Also, I would like to know the best way to document the SSAS Cube. If anyone can send me a sample documentation for me just to use as a base to build my own documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with DAX Studio https://daxstudio.org/, this allows you to run queries on the meta data of the cube (DMV), and get the measure and other information out. Another good tool to use would be Tabular Editor https://tabulareditor.com/.

In DAX studio, you would run a query such as

```
select * from $system.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
```

Which would list the measures, the definition and other metadata about them. You can then query other items to get the relationships, table definitions etc.